# How to implement this pagination plugin in a group of DIV?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, pagination

I have a group of div that contain data from database.

```
<?php  

    foreach($data as $row){
?>

<div id='page-number-all' class='res_div'>
   <input type text value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>
   <input type text value='<?php echo $row['name']; ?>
   <input type text value='<?php echo $row['address']; ?>
</div>

<?php }; ?>
```

I am using this [pagination](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Convenient-Pagination-Plugin-With-Bootstrap-And-jQuery-UI-Pagination-js.html) to display each div. So if I click page one, the first div is show and so on. How can I implement the pagination.

This is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var itemsCount = 55; //for now it's static. But this number should the count of div
var itemsOnPage = 1; //one page one div


var paginationAll = new Pagination({
    container: $("#pagination-all"),
    pageClickCallback: pageClickAll,
    callPageClickCallbackOnInit: true,
    showInput: true,
    showSlider: false,
    enhancedMode: true,
    maxVisibleElements: 20,
    inputTitle: "Go to page"
});
paginationAll.make(itemsCount, itemsOnPage);
});
```

Comment: you're using `id` in foreach loop, so it will generate invalid markup. jQuery will only take first matching div. Use class selector instead of id. It should work.

Comment: in the usage tutorial, only id is allowed. If I change it to class, it's not working so do the tutorial.

Comment: Append unique number to id so it will be unique , and add JavaScript to loop also, so that you get same unique id.

Comment: I don't know why but it still not working. My guess is it has conflict with my responsive tab.